# how to show polymorphic record ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 3 modules Blog, News, Article and I gathering reviews for all.

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :reviewable_type,:reviewable_id,:description,:context,:language,:status, :title, :user_id,:review_category_id,:ratings
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :review_category
  belongs_to :reviewable, :polymorphic => true 

 class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :description, :status, :title
 has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable, :dependent => :destroy

 class News < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :description, :status, :title
 has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable, :dependent => :destroy

 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible:description, :status, :title
 has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable, :dependent => :destroy
```

My question is, how to get all the reviews posted on current user's blog, article, news etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like how you associate other has_many relations. Like this:

```
current_user.blogs.first.reviews
current_user.articles.first.reviews
current_user.news.first.reviews
```

In your blog show page,

```
@blog.reviews.each |r|
  r.review_text
end
```

Comment: Is there any way I can use these in a single line?????
current_user.blogs.first.reviews
current_user.articles.first.reviews
current_user.news.first.review
<br>
**bold**I mean current_user.reviewable.review
because I could have many modules in future where reviews will be required

Answer (score 1):

Because you're trying to call for a `user`, I'd recommend looking at the `User` model too:

```
 #app/models/user.rb
 Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     #User can submit many reviews
     has_many :reviews 

     #User can submit many blogs / news / articles
     has_many :blogs
     has_many :news
     has_many :articles

     def first_blog
        blogs.first
     end
 end

 #app/models/review.rb
 class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :review_category
     belongs_to :reviewable, :polymorphic => true 
 end

 #app/models/blog.rb
 class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable, :dependent => :destroy

     def first_review
        reviews.first
     end
 end

 #app/models/news.rb
 class News < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable, :dependent => :destroy
 end

 #app/models/article.rb
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :reviews, :as => :reviewable, :dependent => :destroy
 end
```

---

**Reviews**

This will allow you to call:

```
#########
#Reviews#
#########

#Submitted
current_user.reviews

#Received
current_user.first_blog.first_review
current_user.first_blog.reviews
```